# Rating plugin. Value 0 is inserted into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using rateit rating plugin for my website (https://rateit.codeplex.com/).
I'm trying to insert the value that a user selects into my database however every time I do this value 0 is inserted. Here is my code (PHP first):

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

}
 else {
header('Location: login.php');
}

$itemid = $_GET['id'];
```

(HTML):

```
<div id="itemreview">
    <form action="" name="review" id="review" method ="post">
    Skin Type: <select name="skintype">
        <option selected="">Skin Type</option> 
        <option value ="Oily">Oily</option>
        <option value ="Mixed">Mixed</option>
        <option value ="Sensitive">Sensitive</option>
        <option value ="Normal">Normal</option>
     </select><br>
Rating: 
<input type="range" value="0" step="0.5" id="rating">
<div id="stars" class="rateit" onclick="" data-rateit-backingfld="#rating"   data-rateit-resetable="false"  data-rateit-ispreset="true"
data-rateit-min="0" data-rateit-max="10">
</div>
  <br>
 <textarea name="review" id="review" cols ="50" rows="8"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submitcomment" id="submit"  value="Comment!">

    </form>
```

Here's my Jquery/Ajax:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#submit').click(function () {


              //Create a variable to hold the value entered by the user
              var stars = $('#stars').rateit('value');

              $.ajax({
                  url: 'itemreview.php',
                  type: "POST",
                  data: { "stars" : stars },
                  success: function (data) {
                      alert("Got it!"+ stars);
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  </script>
```

And here's my php:

```
<?php 
//Insert review into database 

if(isset($_POST['submitcomment'])) {
$skintype = $_POST['skintype'];
$userrating = $_POST['stars'];
$userreview = $_POST['review'];

$insertreview = mysql_query("INSERT INTO itemcomments (itemid, username, commentcontent, ranking, userskintype) VALUE('$itemid', '$username',
           '$userreview', '$userranking', '$skintype')");

           echo "Posted!";
           echo $userrating;
}
?>
```

While I can get the value displayed with the `alert("Got it!"+ stars);` I cannot get the correct value inserted into database when I click submit. 
For example, I rate something for 7.5. After hitting submit I get the alert message "Go it!7.5" but in the database the value inserted is still 0. All other values ($skintype, $userreview, $itemid and $username) are inserted properly.
What might be the issue?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: check for errors, *wall to wall, and treetop tall*

Comment: `$itemid` and `$username` are hiding in a tree somewhere?

Comment: I've edited my post to display other variables as well. Sorry about this.

Comment: again, check for errors. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: so... what did the error functions throw out? did you use them and did you use them properly?

Comment: Ok, I am out of this question. What Puya said about that unnamed input, should have spat out an undefined index notice. Good luck, I am moving on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="range" value="0" step="0.5" id="rating">
```

I think that you need to change the value to value = "" otherwise you'll always get the value zero. Try that ! And let me know. If that doesn't help than i'll look at the code again.

Comment: Thank Puya. It didn't help, the value inserted is still 0. Also, when I change  the value to value = "" then the plugin displays too many stars even if you don't rate.

Comment: Can you print out the $userrating = $_POST['stars']; see what kind of value you get. Simply add this to the code under $userrating = $_POST['stars']; print_r($userrating); exit;

Comment: No, I don't get anything displayed.

Comment: oke so the problem is the ajax. give me a second ;)

Comment: Thank you Puya, I really appreciate your help. I'm still relatively new to Ajax, that might be the cause.

Comment: Oke you forgot to set the name at <input type="range" value="0" step="0.5" id="rating" name="stars">

Comment: that ^ as I told them to do, would have thrown them an undefined index notice. Did they listen to me? I have no idea.

Comment: I had this undefined error earlier but I thought that since I had the value displayed in an alert message it was fine. I'm trying Puya's suggestion now.

Comment: Okay, while I do get the variable $userrating displayed now, the value inserted into database is still 0.

Comment: you got a typo in your query it must be $userrating not $userranking

Comment: This was so easy! Thank you Puya! I'll check your answer as the solution. Thank you.